# What is the meaning of 赶上 in ...完全是赶上了好时代?

Tags: meaning

Can't quite get the meaning of 赶上 here. Any suggestions please?

> 像她这样一个铁路工人家庭出身、没上过大学、貌不出众的文工团演员，一步步地走到今天，成为一个集制片人、导演、演员于一身的大明星，完全是赶上了好时代。

完全是*赶上*了*好时代*。 totally (赶上)*in time for??* the (好时代）*golden era*??

赶上：to keep up with， to catch up with， to overtake， to chance upon， in time for

Answer (score 4):

"In time for" is the right interpretation in this context. 好时代(an era when living was great) is like a party. It has a beginning and an end. People who died before it or born after it missed out. "她赶上了好时代" means she was born at the right time, during a great era.

赶上 means " (rushed in or hurriedly arrive) **just in time**."

Answer (score 1):

In time for, or to chance upon. I think both are OK. Maybe it'll be clearer if you understand the context.

It is mentioned in the sentence that she was born in a railway worker family with poor education, and was a plain-looking average actress in the art troupe.

(That means she should not have succeeded.)

However she finally achieved her success as a producer, a director and a famous actress. If it was not for a golden era, she would not be so successful.

Comment: 完全 here is what?

Comment: @Gangosa You can take it as `totally`. It is totally because of the era.